# How to configure Web Api 2 and IIS for Basic Authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

**Scenario**

- I've a Web Api 2.2 RESTful service made with VS2012 C#
- I'm using Basic authentication with a custom check user/pass (works fine)
- Some methods has `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute
- Several methods are using `[Authorize(Roles = "myRol")]`
- In local works as well (read the user and pass, check it with the database, denies or allow when it must, allow anonymous when should, etc)

---

**Problem**

When I deployed the service in the DEV environment for the first time, I could'nt log in:

- Methods with AllowAnonymous returns `200`
- Methods with basic security returns `401`

---

**Data** *(please ask or comment for an update on this)*

This is my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
  <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="WebHostBasicAuth.Modules.BasicAuthHttpModule, myAssemblyName" />
</modules>
```

This is my header (it works in local):

```
Authorization: Basic YXR1cG9uZTp0ZXN0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and this is my response:

**Status**:`401 Unauthorized`
**Data**: `{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`
**Header**:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Fri, 24 Apr 2015 14:36:27 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 61
Expires: -1
```

This is my IIS configuration (If I set in "**on**" the Basic Authentication, the IIS ask me for credentials that I don't have and/or they are invalid):

[image: IIS Config]

---

**Question:**

Is this well configurated? I miss something?
How can I see a log or something about what is the internal error of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add the database to the dev environment? VS Creates a small database kind of hidden when you start a project with the provided authentication. You need to push the database to the dev server.

Comment: @AntoineLev There is a custom authentication with my custom user/rol model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your authorization code can't connect with the database.

Comment out the code that connects to the DB and return true regardless and see if it lets you through. Use elimination to narrow down to where the problem is. You need to update the DB connection strings (web.config) etc. to match with dev environment. You can't expect what worked on local to work in another environment if you didn't adjust accordingly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. It was about an escalated issue with the DAS. The DAS was return 401, so you were near.